# Solution of a Dirichlet problem on the unit disk with different boundary conditions for y<0 and y>0

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

The questions is asking me to find the solution to the Dirichlet problem given that

$ϕ_{xx} + ϕ_{yy} = 0,  \qquad x^2 + y^2 < 1$
$ϕ(x,y) = 100,         \qquad x^2 + y^2 < 1,\ y > 0$
$ϕ(x,y) = 0,           \qquad x^2 + y^2 < 1, \ y < 0$

Also, $T(z) = \frac{i(1-z)}{1+z} $ maps the unit disk $|z|<1$ conformally onto the upper half plane $Im(w)>0$

Looking at the boundary $|z|=1$, I know that T would map this circle either to a line or a circle. Because the pole $z=-1$ lies on the circle, it's a line. Using $ z= -i, 1, i$ as test points, I've found that in the w-plane, this line is just $v=0$.

For reference, $T(-i) = -1, T(-1) = \infty,  T(1) = 0$ and $T(i) = 1$

However, because of the boundary conditions that are different for $y<0$ and $y>0$, I'm not sure how to pinpoint where the BCs lie on the w-plane.

I am not to use the Poisson integral formula

Comment: The boundary of the disk is split at $1$ and $-1$. So you need to look at the two "arcs" between $T(1)$ and $T(-1)$ - which means the two arcs are the negative and the positive real half-axis respectively. Since $T(-i) = -1$, the lower semicircle is mapped to the negative half-axis.

Comment: I'm confused as to how you got two arcs between $T(1)$ and $T(-1) $ since $T(1) = 0$ and $T(-1) = \infty$.
Do we just conclude that because $T(-i) = -1$, then the arc (in the z-plane) containing $z=-i$ is mapped to the negative half axis? And from $u=0$ onwards, the part that is mapped to the positive real half axis in the w-plane is the circular arc where $y>0$?

Comment: $T$ maps the boundary of the unit disk to $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ (the boundary of the upper half-plane). The points $1$ and $-1$ split the unit circle into two arcs, and since $T$ is an automorphism of the Riemann sphere, it follows that the points $T(1)$ and $T(-1)$ split the circle $\mathbb{R}\cup \{\infty\}$ into two arcs, corresponding to the arcs of the unit circle. Then it only remains to check which arc corresponds to which.

Comment: Lovely! Thank you! :)

Answer (score 1):

The analytical solution can be expressed on explicit form in polar coordinates. The boundary condition is a well-known Fourier series. Then, coming back to the Cartesian coordinates leads to the solution of the PDE according to the boundary conditions.

[image]

(Typo corrected in attachment)